# История C++. Разноименные методы с одинаковым функционалом

Tags: c++, stl, история

Вот мне стало интересно после долгой работы с контейнерными классами STL Library C++, зачем в многие из них были добавлены разноименные методы с одинаковым функционалом? Так, например, если рассмотреть класс string, то:

```
std::string::size() === std::string::length();
```

Методы разноименны, но функционал один и тот же. Вопрос - зачем? Это как-то связано с историей C, или одной группе разработчиков STL тупо не понравился метод `size()` и они решили добавить свой `length()` ? Также можно привести пример всех ассоциативных классов STL:

```
std::vector<class T>::at()  === std::vector::operator [];
```

**Зачем это? Они отличаются скоростью работы? Или, может, все-таки специфичной начинкой?**

Comment: Да просто так) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905479/stdstring-length-and-size-member-functions

Answer (score 4):

Начну с простого. Методы at() и operator[] - совсем не одно и то же. at() предоставляет безопасный доступ к элементам коллекции. Если происходит выход за пределы коллекции, метод at() выбрасывает исключение, а operator[] - нет. Однако, за безопасность приходится платить более медленной работой at().

Comment: Благодарю! Этой тонкости, признаюсь, не знал! Теперь известно, что это разные вещи...но как быть с определением количества хранимых элементов в шаблонном классе? Правда ли, что это "просто так"? Но, как известно, в программировании ничего не бывает "просто так"...

Comment: Не понял вопроса про количество. Тут дело не в количестве, а в том, что в некоторых контейнерах (vector, list, string) элементы расположены линейно. Выход за пределы этого ряда, обращение к несуществующим элементам - штука очень неприятная. Лучшее, что она может вызвать - аварийное завершение программы.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то можно было заглянуть в первоисточник, а именно [исходный код библиотеки STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/string) и убедиться самому, что ф-ции `size()` и `length()` возвращают одно и то же. Сделано так потому что ф-ции `size()` х-ны для всех контейнеров STL, но для строк логичнее брать не размер, а длину (`length`).

```
public:                         // Size, capacity, etc.
  size_type size() const { return _M_finish - _M_start; }
  size_type length() const { return size(); }
```

UPD: касательно `wstring` хочу обратить внимание на один момент. Размер строки и длина строки (в символах) может отличаться. Но при этом `size` и `length` возвращают одно и то же. Этому посвящен [этот вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183736/stdwstring-length)

Comment: То есть length() используется для наглядности?

Comment: Да, чтобы были говорящие названия методов.

Comment: Хм, вот, значит, в чем суть - в простой наглядности! Наверное все эти мелочи типа этой и составляют всю гибкость и мощность языка C++, подтвержденную десятилетиями...

**Спасибо!**

Comment: @Asen Вообще, как рассказывают, Страуструп придумал `C++` на спор :)

Comment: Котик, можно указать источник таких сведений?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, классная новость! Тоже хочется узнать об этом поподробнее =)

Comment: На самом деле, это еще ни о чем не говорит. С++, конечно, та еще штучка... но нормальной альтернативы пока нет (((

Comment: @mikillskegg

- Хм, я, наверно, когда по диагонал читал [вот это,][1] не понял, что это пародия. Правда, судя по результатам гугла, не только я - это интервью, если не сильно размышлять, довольно правдоподобно :)

>  **Stroustrup:**

>   It was only supposed to be a joke, I never thought people would
   take the book seriously. Anyone with half a brain can see that
   object-oriented programming is counter-intuitive, illogical and
   inefficient.

[1]: http://artlung.com/smorgasborg/Invention_of_Cplusplus.shtml

Comment: Прочитал, что на спор, сначала подумал, что может быть, полез в инет, конечно не нашел. Зато нашел [вот это](http://lurkmore.to/C%2B%2B). 

Любителей крестов прошу не обижаться, просто посмейтесь.

Comment: @Asen, согласитесь, С++ сложен, а перевешивают ли достоинства языка этот (сложность) недостаток - большой вопрос.

По сути в С++ (и в Java тоже) смешаны два существенно разных инструмента. 

Один - это простой,  надежный язык (набор инструментов) для *прикладного* (в идеале проблемно-ориентированного) уровня. 

Другой - набор средств, позволяющий конструировать набор номер 1. 

А язык (и инструментарий разработки (компилятор, библиотеки)) тот же самый. Вот и возникают на практике ошибки, ошибки и еще раз ошибки. 

Реальная проблема, типа обезъяна с гранатой (усугубляется IDE).

Comment: @avp, да, этот язык правда сложен в изучении. Я бы сказал, это самый сложный язык, который мне только приходилось изучать( даже ассемблер( посчитаем его за язык ) и тот легче! )! Чего мне только, как помню, понять для чего нужны указатели. Раньше считал полным бредом, сейчас понял, как это важно для создания гибкости, да программирования вцелом( я не про одни только указатели ). Но тем не менее, в C++ ничего не стоит "себе прострелить ногу"! Но это уже скорее, вопрос аккуратности...

---
Но, когда я что-л. делаю на этом языке, я чувствую, что строю "по кирпичикам", а не "по блокам", как в C#

Comment: @Asen, вот только указатели именно к С++ отношения не имеют. 

Указатель, он и в африке указатель (что на ассемблере, что в Си, что в Java (там их стыдливо называют ссылками)), компиляторы только разной сговоривости.

Проблема в большом количестве свойств у *кирпичиков* из которых строят *блоки*, предназначаемые для создания других блоков, из которых в свою очередь делают новые блоки, подразумевая при этом использовать их (новые большие блоки) в *разнообразных* конструкциях.

При этом KISS принцип обычно теряется напрочь. Отсюда сложность программ и как следствие ошибки.

Comment: @Котик http://artlung.com/smorgasborg/Invention_of_Cplusplus.shtml -- это первоапрельская шутка неустановленного автора. Страуструп к ней отношения не имеет. А вообще достоинства C++ вполне компенсируются его недостатками.